# How to format C Drive in windows which has an older windows

Tags: windows

I have Windows Vista in C Drive and Windows 7 in E drive. I am using windows 7 only these days, I want to format C drive and just use it to store my files (basically remove the OS).

How can I format it? I tried right clicking and quick format but it says "Windows was unable to complete the format"

Comment: I suggest you post a picture of your disk management. We have to first find out which of your partitions is the active partition - chances are it is the Vista partition.

Comment: -1 if you expanded your answer to give more info, to say look at disk management, here's what to do if it is the active partition, here's what to do if it's not e.t.c. and you covered all bases for him or a person in his  position, to go start to finish, that'd enable him/them to format his/their drive, then it'd be an answer, but what you've written is not. Often people e.g. you, think that the questioner needs to clarify, when technically they don't. And sometimes you can give a more complete answer if they don't or if you answer as if they didnt and that can help more people

Comment: You are most likely booting from that drive, so you cannot format it. But you can just delete the files you don't need and use it after that, possibly removing Vista from the boot menu if necessary. Just don't remove the boot files.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/210983-dual-boot-delete-os.html) link or [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/uninstall-windows-7-on-a-multiboot-system) link

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that you still have a pagefile on the C drive. Right click on Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Performances Settings -> Advanced -> Change, and disable the pagefile on the C drive.